# UWP windows 10 Visibility Binding to a global Variable

Tags: uwp

I am trying to bind the visibility of a control to a Global variable:

I have a Visibility Converter:

```cs
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public bool IsReversed { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (value is bool && (bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

I also created a class that inherits from DependencyObject:

```cs
public class Verified : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerifiedUserNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "VerifiedUserName",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(Verified),
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty)
    );

    public string VerifiedUserName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(VerifiedUserNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VerifiedUserNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVerifiedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsVerified",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(Verified),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(IsVerifiedChanged))
    );

    public bool IsVerified
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsVerifiedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsVerifiedProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void IsVerifiedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Verified container = d as Verified;
        bool latestIsVerifiedValue = (bool)e.NewValue;
        if (latestIsVerifiedValue == true)
        {
            //To Do
        }
    }
}
```

in my App.xaml I created to variables:

```cs
public static Verified myValidator = new Verified();

public static BooleanToVisibilityConverter myConverter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter();
```

In a simple page I added a text box and I want to bind it's Visibility to the myValidator variable.

In order to accomplish that I am creating the binding in code:

```cs
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Source = App.myValidator;
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("IsVerified");
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
myBinding.Converter = App.myConverter;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(txtName2, VisibilityProperty, myBinding);
```

In the App.xaml: I am setting the value of my Validator this way :

```cs
App.myValidator.IsVerified = false;
```

When I navigate to the simple page the text box is not visible (OK).

To test the behavior, I added a button on my screen and added code to change the value of myValidator.isVerified.

As I change the value of my App.myValidator.IsVerified the visibility of the textbox does not change. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in the converter and see if it's actually getting hit. I suspect it isn't.

Comment: It is getting to the converter the first time. The propertyChange event  of the validator when I change the value of IsVerified is executed correctly all the time. But after the first time converter does not get hit again.

Comment: Not sure if this will do it, but try also inheriting from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and implementing that, then see if it works.

Comment: This did it! I implemented the same solution but instead of inheriting from  DependencyObject I used INotifyPropertyChanged. Now it works just the way I wanted. Thank you very much for your help. I am not sure but it looks like you have to enter your answer in a different way so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

The binding system uses reflection to look for property, it does not look for "field".

When you declare

```
public static Verified myValidator = new Verified();
```

You're declaring a field, not a property.

Change your myValidator in App.cs to a property would fix the issue, as below,

```
public static Verified myValidator { get; set; } = new Verified();
```

Update!
The reason it works was because I accidentally declare a Verified property inside MainPage.cs,

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public Verified myValidator1 {get; set;} // the property name does not matter

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Not sure why it works, I'm still looking into it.

Comment: I did this and it did not work. I think I tried it before, I have tried multiple combinations but no success. At some point it was working, when I was doing the binding in a declarative way using resources. But I can not find a way to do it with the global variable.

Comment: I realized I had a Verified instance declared(public Verified myVerified { get; set; }) in MainPage.cs, where txtName2 is declared. It seems so weird to me adding this line of code makes the binding works.

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue is that your property isn't sending out a changed event, so your binding isn't even aware that the property has changed, much less that it should call your conversion method. Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` should notify it when the property changes, and it should then call the converter and do what you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I can reproduce this issue on my side. 
To verify the root cause, I registered the Verified.IsVerifiedProperty's PropertyChanged Callback:

```
private long token;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
            token = App.myValidator.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(Verified.IsVerifiedProperty, ChangedCallback);
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}

private void ChangedCallback(DependencyObject sender, DependencyProperty dp)
{
            if (dp == Verified.IsVerifiedProperty)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ChangedCallback" + sender.GetValue(dp));
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ChangedCallback" + txtName2.Visibility);
            }
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
            App.myValidator.UnregisterPropertyChangedCallback(Verified.IsVerifiedProperty, token);
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```

The PropertyChanged couldn't be triggered as expected, so the solution is implement the **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface for Verified class:

```
public class Verified : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVerifiedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "IsVerified",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(Verified),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(IsVerifiedChanged))
        );

        public bool IsVerified
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsVerifiedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsVerifiedProperty, value);
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsVerified"));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private static void IsVerifiedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Verified container = d as Verified;
            bool latestIsVerifiedValue = (bool)e.NewValue;
            if (latestIsVerifiedValue == true)
            {
                //To Do
            }
        }
}
```